# A partition on my external Seagate 4TB suddenly won't mount

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a 4TB Seagate External Drive that is evenly split into two partitions. One side is used for Time Machine backups on my Mac, the other is used to store Photos and Videos taken over the years. I've had this setup working for several years without issue. Today, I discovered the partition storing the Photos and Videos is completely missing.

I opened up Disk Utility to see what was wrong, and the partition is showing up as this:

[Disk Utility Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwoZK.png)

When I click the Mount button, nothing happens. Clicking First Aid causes it to return this error:

[First Aid error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoaG9.png)

I opened up the Terminal and tried running the following commands to no success:

[Picture of Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLQe7.png)

I have a Windows 7 installed via Bootcamp on the Mac, so booted into there hoping it will read it, but it doesn't seem to work. I also have a PC running Windows 10 which I tried it on, and it had the same results. For both Windows machines, when I give it a letter in Disk Management it says it needs to be formatted before I can use it. I would rather not format it because I have years worth of pictures, videos, and Time Machine backups on here. On both machines, when I try to open it with File Explorer, I get a "Drive is not accessible, the Parameter is Incorrect" error. Here is a picture of the drive showing up in Disk Management (The Seagate is Disk 2):

[Windows computer management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EItqK.png)

An easy way out would be to just format the partition, but I would rather not lose all those videos and photos on there. How do I get access to this partition again without losing all the contents on it?